# Adding 2 different Ads After Paragraph of WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to add 2 different advertisements after a post in wordpress

I have tried to use this code. But it didnt work. Can someone help?

```
$ad_code = 'ad code 1';
$ad_code2 = 'ad code 2';
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
  $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
  $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code2, 6, $content );
  return $content;
}

// Parent Function

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
  $closing_p = '</p>';
  $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
  foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }
    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
  }
  return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_ads_to_content' );

function add_ads_to_content( $content ) {

    $ads = array(
        2 =>  'ad code 1', // paragraph_id => ad_code
        4 => 'ad code 2', // paragraph_id => ad_code
        6 => 'ad code 3' // paragraph_id => ad_code
    );

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        foreach ($ads as $paragraph_id => $ad_code) {
            $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $paragraph_id, $content );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Comment: This is indeed amazing. I now want to add an else statement where it outputs different ad code if the posts are AMP. I used the AMP end point. Please see the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Faruk - thank you so much. I wrote an else statement where it would display a different code for AMP posts. However, this doesnt seem to work. Is there a more eleg

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_ads_to_content' );

function add_ads_to_content( $content ) {

    $ads = array(
        2 =>  'ad code', // paragraph_id => ad_code
        6 => 'ad code', // paragraph_id => ad_code
    );
///ad array 2
        $ads2 = array(
        2 =>  'ad code', // paragraph_id => ad_code
        6 => 'ad code', // paragraph_id => ad_code
    );
///statements
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        foreach ($ads as $paragraph_id => $ad_code) {
            $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $paragraph_id, $content );
        }
    }
    
    elseif ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) { if(is_amp_endpoint())
        foreach ($ads2 as $paragraph_id => $ad_code2) {
            $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code2, $paragraph_id, $content );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```